# How to get the result of a Callback function inside of an callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I use express on NodeJS, and I want to get a result of a callback function.

```
function yts(s) {
return youTube.search(s, 5, function(error, result) {
    var res;
    var json = []
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.send("error");
  }
  else {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
    res = result["items"];
    var i = 0;
    while (res[i]) {
        //console.log(i + " | " + res[i]["id"]["videoId"] + " | " + res[i]["snippet"]["title"] + " | " + "https://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ res[i]["id"]["videoId"] +"/0.jpg");
        json.push({videoID: res[i]["id"]["videoId"], title: res[i]["snippet"]["title"]});
        i++;
    }
      console.log(json);
      //Get json
    }
  });
}

app.get('/search/:title', function (req, res) {
   res.send(JSON.stringify(yts(req.params["title"])));
});
```

I am using [youtube-node (NPM)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-node) to search youtube and returning the most important inforamtion back to the User. 
How can I make that //Get json return the code somehow back to app.get function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your function into a [callback function](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced) in order to return the response as soon as it retrieves it from YouTube.

```js
function yts(s, callback) {
  youTube.search(s, 5, function(error, result) {
    var res;
    var json = [];
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.send("error");
    } else {
      res = result["items"];
      var i = 0;
      while (res[i]) {
        json.push({videoID: res[i]["id"]["videoId"], title: res[i]["snippet"]["title"]});
        i++;
      }
      callback(json);
    }
  });
}

app.get('/search/:title', function (req, res) {
  yts(req.params["title"], function (jsonRes){
    res.send(JSON.stringify(jsonRes));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a **callback** to which you pass the result, or **promisify** the function and **await** it.

You also have to realize that in the `yts` function, you do not have access to `res`, so you cannot do `res.send()`.

### With callbacks

```
function yts(s, cb) {
  youTube.search(s, 5, function(error, result) {
    var res;
    var json = []
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      cb("error");
    }
    else {
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
      res = result["items"];
      var i = 0;
      while (res[i]) {
        //console.log(i + " | " + res[i]["id"]["videoId"] + " | " + res[i]["snippet"]["title"] + " | " + "https://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ res[i]["id"]["videoId"] +"/0.jpg");
        json.push({videoID: res[i]["id"]["videoId"], title: res[i]["snippet"]["title"]});
        i++;
      }
      console.log(json);
      cb(null, json);
      //Get json
    }
  });
}

app.get('/search/:title', function (req, res) {
  yts(req.params["title"], function(err, json){
    if(err)
      return res.send(err);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(json));
  })
});
```

### With promises

```
async function yts(s) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    youTube.search(s, 5, function(error, result) {
      var res;
      var json = []
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        reject("error");
      }
      else {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
        res = result["items"];
        var i = 0;
        while (res[i]) {
          //console.log(i + " | " + res[i]["id"]["videoId"] + " | " + res[i]["snippet"]["title"] + " | " + "https://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ res[i]["id"]["videoId"] +"/0.jpg");
          json.push({videoID: res[i]["id"]["videoId"], title: res[i]["snippet"]["title"]});
          i++;
        }
        console.log(json);
        resolve(json);
        //Get json
      }
    });  
  })
}

app.get('/search/:title', async function (req, res) {
  try{
    var json = await req.params["title"];
    res.send(JSON.stringify(json));
  }catch(err){
    res.send(err);
  }
});
```